# Creating a dataframe on Date from two incomplete, not same size dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis, stock

I am trying to put together a big dataframe wih dates, average sentiment scores (from Twitter), and closing stock price.

Here is what I have so far.

```
#imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import re
import urllib3
import requests
import datetime 

#mydates dataframe that just has the dates from my desired range. Shape is 2008 rows x 1 column
date1='2014-01-01'
date2='2019-07-01'
mydates =pd.date_range(date1,date2).tolist()
newdf =pd.DataFrame({'Date':mydates})

#df with the average daily sentiment scores. Large dataset with 500 rows.
#This currently skips dates that didn't have tweets.I want to include those dates but have sentiment equal 0.
Date        Score
2014-01-13  0.01
2014-01-14  0.035
2014-01-15  0.453
2014-01-20  0.06474

#ts dataframe of dates and stock prices. Shape is 1381 rows x 1 column
Date         Adj Close
2014-01-13  44.8
2014-01-14  45.3
2014-01-15  45.8
2014-01-16  46.5
2014-01-17  46.5
2014-01-21  46.7
```

**Desired output**

```
Date        Score   Close Price
2014-01-13  0.01     44.8
2014-01-14  0.035    45.3
2014-01-15  0.453    45.8
2014-01-16  0.0      46.5
2014-01-17  0.0      46.5
2014-01-18  0.0      46.5
2014-01-19  0.0      46.5
2014-01-20  0.06474  46.5
```

My plan is to then save this dataset as a csv.

Issues I've run into:
Df and ts are NOT the same size. I'd need to go through ts to make all the weekend close prices the same as Friday. How do I do that?
Not knowing how to write a loop that can assign the score for a date in one dataframe to a column in another dataframe.

I use pandas-3.

Comment: The first thing you'll want to do is `merge` these two data frames on the date value.  Search the site for "merge dataframe on date" and you will see many examples.  Check your data frames first with df.info() to ensure the dtypes are both "datetime" objects to enable the merge.  Several options with merge to fill missing values and you should merge "on" the dataframe with the more complete set of dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the index of `df` as `Date` and use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) to reindex the dataframe on daily frequency, then using [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `left` merge it with `ts` on column `Date`, finally use [`Series.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html) on column `Adj Close`:

```
df1 = (
    df.set_index('Date').
    asfreq('D', fill_value=0).reset_index().merge(ts, on='Date', how='left')
)
df1['Adj Close'] = df1['Adj Close'].ffill()
```

Result:

```
print(df1)
        Date    Score  Adj Close
0 2014-01-13  0.01000       44.8
1 2014-01-14  0.03500       45.3
2 2014-01-15  0.45300       45.8
3 2014-01-16  0.00000       46.5
4 2014-01-17  0.00000       46.5
5 2014-01-18  0.00000       46.5
6 2014-01-19  0.00000       46.5
7 2014-01-20  0.06474       46.5
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One complication is that I used df.groupby(df.Date), so when I tried to set the index of df as Date I got an error saying Date wasn't in the column.

Comment: @NeedyTween Can you include the output of  `df.groupby(df.Date)` in the question, so that i can see the issue?

Comment: df.index returns this: Float64Index([], dtype='float64', name='Date')

which is confusing to me since the Average Sentiment datatype is float

Comment: Lets continue the discussion  [HERE](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218466/casual-discussions)?

Answer (score 0):

To merge two pandas dataframes on a common column, use the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) function. To specify that you want to keep rows with dates in `ts`, but not in `df`, use the `how='left'` option, like so:

```
ts.merge(df, on='Date', how='left', sort=False)

# output:
# Date       Close Score
# 2014-01-13 44.8 0.010
# 2014-01-14 45.3 0.035
# 2014-01-15 45.8 0.453
# 2014-01-16 46.5 NaN
# 2014-01-17 46.5 NaN
# 2014-01-21 46.7 NaN
```

You can also use `.fillna(0)` method to replace the NaN values with 0, as in your desired output.

```
ts.merge(df, on='Date', how='left', sort=False).fillna(0)

# output:
# Date       Close Score
# 2014-01-13 44.8 0.010
# 2014-01-14 45.3 0.035
# 2014-01-15 45.8 0.453
# 2014-01-16 46.5 0
# 2014-01-17 46.5 0
# 2014-01-21 46.7 0
```

This is a common operation known as a *left join*, which is why you have to specify `how='left'`.

A left join will keep all rows from the first table, regardless of whether there is a matching row in the second table. The final result will keep all rows of the first table but will omit the un-matched row from the second table. Here's how it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) with [`df.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
r = pd.date_range(start=df.Date.min(), end=df.Date.max())

df = df.set_index('Date').reindex(r).fillna(0.0).rename_axis('Date').reset_index()

ts['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['Date'])
r1 = pd.date_range(start=ts.Date.min(), end=ts.Date.max()) 

ts = ts.set_index('Date').reindex(r1).ffill().rename_axis('Date').reset_index()

result = df.merge(ts, on='Date')

print(result)
```

Output:

```
        Date    Score  Adj_Close
0 2014-01-13  0.01000       44.8
1 2014-01-14  0.03500       45.3
2 2014-01-15  0.45300       45.8
3 2014-01-16  0.00000       46.5
4 2014-01-17  0.00000       46.5
5 2014-01-18  0.00000       46.5
6 2014-01-19  0.00000       46.5
7 2014-01-20  0.06474       46.5
```